# Coroutine Job Restart

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have implemented a timer to advance the progress on a linear progress indicator.

```
private val timerjob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch (start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        while (timerProgress.floatValue < 1.0F) {
            delay(10)
            timerProgress.floatValue += .0020F
            Log.d("Timer", timerProgress.toString())
        }
        timerProgress.floatValue = 0.0F
        gameState = GameState.AwaitingSelection
        main()
```

As you probably know this works once and only once. However I need it to run whenever I call it. How do I go about implementing that?

I tried running it inside a function but then I lost the ability to start/cancel so that didn't pan out.